# ABCjs: can't set clef in K info field if mode not fully specified and image is cached

Tags: bug, abcjs

**`See end of post for workaround`**

---

The following three ABC code samples should be equivalent:

```
X:0         X:0            X:0
K:C bass    K:Cmaj bass    K:C major bass
A,,B,,C,    A,,B,,C,       A,,B,,C,
```

However, the first image displays incorrectly if it has been previously displayed and cached by the browser.

To reproduce, if the image immediately below looks correct, reload the page, and it produces the image at the bottom of this post.

```
X:0
K:C bass
A,,B,,C,
```

Whereas the other two both render correctly regardless whether they were previously cached, as follows.

```
X:0
K:C major bass
A,,B,,C,
```

---

The incorrect image looks like this.
[image: bad rendering]

---

**Reproduced on**

Widows 10 (v. 2004) with

- Chrome 85.0.4183.121 (on 2 machines)
- Edge 85.0.564.63
- Firefox 81.0 (on 2 machines; clean install. Behavior is different, however. First time opening page, display incorrect. Okay on refresh.)

MacOS 10.15.7 with

- Chrome 85.0.4183.121
- Safari 14.0

---

WORKAROUND

Reload the page with a [cache bypass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache). On Windows this is generally done with `CTRL+F5`; on MacOS, `CMD+SHIFT+R`.

Comment: Aaron - those two images look identical to me. What is it you are seeing?

Comment: @DoktorMayhem Appears to be platform/browser specific. Please see edit.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem Okay, not browser specific. The problem appears to be in rendering the image when it was previously cached by the browser. I can reproduce on Win10 with Edge and Chrome. Clearing the cache and reloading the page "fixes" the problem.

Comment: @Aaron For what it's worth, I can't reproduce this on Fedora using Firefox 80.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce on Chrome and Safari on macOS 10.15.7

Comment: I can also reproduce with Firefox on Windows 10, but the behavior is somewhat different. It seems like the second and/or third time I refresh, the image is "bad" but then it's okay after that.

Comment: I'm not sure there's caching since the staff is generated on-the-fly by the JavaScript on the client's browser, not stored as an image on the server. Maybe buggy interaction between the script and the browser.

Comment: @AndrewT. Not sure I follow. It's image caching on the client side that seems to be the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if ABCjs convert the notation to an image file and cache it (you can't right-click on it and save it as an image). Based on my experiment, it always redraw the notation as an SVG on-the-fly (if it's cached, disabling JavaScript will still show the image)

Comment: @AndrewT. Just to clarify, are you able to reproduce the problem itself?

Comment: Yes, repro on Chrome 85 on macOS 10.15.6.

Comment: @AndrewT.Cool. Okay, so if the image itself isn't being cached, can you speculate on why clearing the cache seems to fix the problem?

Comment: For that specific issue, unfortunately I don't know the reason. I only know that [SE is using version 2.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVHkK.png) while [ABCjs Editor](https://www.abcjs.net/abcjs-editor.html) is using [version 5.9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us7FE.png), if that's the concern.

Comment: Clearing the cache doesn't fix the problem for me, particularly on the sandbox page.  (Safari 14.0 on MacOS 10.14.6.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Hmm...Your code renders okay for me on Chrome, but only after clearing my cache and refreshing the page. The bug was previously confirmed on Safari 14 with MacOS 10.15.7, so maybe there's even more going on. Do any of the samples on the sandbox page render for you, or is the problem global for all ABC code?

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 86.0.4240.75, Windows 10.  I was wondering why the answers I was reading made no sense.