# Strange issue with ABCjs

Tags: bug, abcjs

I recently [answered a question](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/116419/74331), and I wanted to add notation to provide a better explanation.

I'm not yet as experienced as I'd like to, but I tested the code both in the sandbox and in the "official" editor, and they *did* look fine. After some changes, I did begin to face some strange issues. I tried to fix them, and I also faced unexpected and *unreliable* behavior (even when trying with private mode and after clearing the cache).

So, the code is in three parts (one for each example):

### First example

```
X: 0
K: C
L: 1/4
_B, C _D _E F G A _B
C _D _E F G A _B c
```

### Second example

```
X: 1
K: C
L: 1/4
_G _A __B _c _d _e f _g
_A __B _c _d _e f _g _a
```

### Third example

```
X: 2
K: C
L: 1/4
^G A B ^c ^d ^e ^f ^g
A B ^c ^d ^e ^f ^g a
```

At the time of writing, I really don't know how this would result but I can provide screenshots of what I'm getting on my browsers. What puzzles me is that I get "wrong" result in newer (but not so-updated) browsers than in olders.

Chrome (*very* old, version 46.0.2490.71):

[image: chrome screenshot]

Chromium (pretty old, version 59.0.3071.104):

[image: chromium screenshot]

Firefox (slightly old, version 78.0), similar to Chromium:

[image: firefox screenshot]

An interesting aspect is that with both Chromium *and* Firefox I can see, for an instant, the tab visualization.

I know that I'm not using the latest versions of any of those browsers (for technical problems, I cannot upgrade them right now), but I'm not sure about the source of the issue. I don't know if it's a cache issue, caused by my previous editing attempts (but I cannot absolutely be certain about it), as it took me a while to get the example as I wanted, but I'm also worried about people who cannot, for any valid reason, install a "recent" version of the browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ABCjs: can't set clef in K info field if mode not fully specified and image is cached](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3556/abcjs-cant-set-clef-in-k-info-field-if-mode-not-fully-specified-and-image-is-c)

Comment: If you press CTRL+F5 (Windows) or CMD+SHIFT+R (Mac), it will display correctly (until the next time you visit the post).

Comment: @Aaron thanks for the other question, it seems a similar problem, but, as said, clearing/ignoring the cache doesn't solve the problem at least on Firefox (interestingly enough, I can see it properly rendered on Chromium *today*). I also tried in private mode, with another profile, and by bypassing the cache with the browser console without seeing any difference, similarly to what some pointed out in the related post (so, technically it *could* be a duplicate, but it doesn't *really* answer the question).

Comment: You are [not the first person to have or indeed report this problem](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abcjs?tab=Newest), but a hard refresh has so fae always solved the problem for folks that have had it